# Get perforce data into a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, database, api, perforce

I'm curious as if anyone has used any method of getting data from perforce into a managed language.  I've found a few sample applications out there, and I'm hoping someone here has had success in doing this and could offer some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of "data" are you talking about, and what Perforce version are you talkiing about, and what version of .NET are you talking about, and in general, what are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have in our application using the [P4.NET library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p4dotnet/). It works OK, however we wrapped it as the interface was difficult to work with. P4.NET is not supported by Perforce and is probably missing a few features.

I have considered running SWIG on the C++ library and create a our own managed library but haven't had the chance (time) to do so.

**EDIT** Just re-read my post and it's absolutely gibberish. Let's try again...

We have used the P4.NET library in our application, it works OK. It's interface is a little ugly and we wrote a wrapper hide it and expose the functionality we wanted. Writing a wrapper is a good idea anyways as it gives us the option/flexibility to swap the VC system out with SVN or GIT (why you would if you can use Perforce I don't know...).

I have look briefly at the option of running SWIG against the Perforce C++ library and creating our own wrapper with a cleaner interface but it hasn't been a high priority task as P4.NET works.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I linked to a SourceForge project.

Comment: Best alternative that I would consider is https://github.com/inorton/XR.Mono.Perforce - it needs to be packaged and made available on nuget.